# Listen to root window events using X11

Tags: c++, linux, events, x11

I've been trying for a while to achieve this but I can't.
XNextEvent is never called.
I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.
This is the code I have so far.
I want to print both clicks and mouse moves.
I've tried using XAllowEvents, XGrabPointer it won't work. Why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>

char *key_name[] = {
    "first",
    "second (or middle)",
    "third",
    "fourth",  // :D
    "fivth"    // :|
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Display *display;
    XEvent xevent;
    Window window;

    if( (display = XOpenDisplay(NULL)) == NULL )
        return -1;

    window = DefaultRootWindow(display);
    XAllowEvents(display, AsyncBoth, CurrentTime);

    XGrabPointer(display, 
                 window,
                 1, 
                 PointerMotionMask | ButtonPressMask | ButtonReleaseMask , 
                 GrabModeAsync,
                 GrabModeAsync, 
                 None,
                 None,
                 CurrentTime);

    while(1) {
        XNextEvent(display, &xevent);

        switch (xevent.type) {
            case MotionNotify:
                printf("Mouse move      : [%d, %d]\n", xevent.xmotion.x_root, xevent.xmotion.y_root);
                break;
            case ButtonPress:
                printf("Button pressed  : %s\n", key_name[xevent.xbutton.button - 1]);
                break;
            case ButtonRelease:
                printf("Button released : %s\n", key_name[xevent.xbutton.button - 1]);
                break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Everything in the X Window System requires an X display to be initialized. It's not for accessing raw devices directly.

Comment: If you want to get the window's name, then there must be an X display. Linux doesn't have windows without X.

Comment: The raw device doesn't know anything about windows, it's just a bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

[XSelectInput](https://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/libX11/libX11/libX11.html#Selecting_Events) is your friend.

> There are two ways to select the events you want reported to your client application. One way is to set the event_mask member of the XSetWindowAttributes structure when you call XCreateWindow and XChangeWindowAttributes. Another way is to use XSelectInput.

The functions you're looking for to obtain window informations are [XQueryTree](https://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/libX11/libX11/libX11.html#XQueryTree) or [XQueryPointer](https://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/libX11/libX11/libX11.html#XQueryPointer). See also the complete list: [Obtaining Window Information](https://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/libX11/libX11/libX11.html#Obtaining_Window_Information).